# Can eigenvalues of a correlation matrix be negative?

Tags: matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, correlation, positive-semidefinite

Can eigenvalues of a correlation matrix be negative?

I am a bit confused because I know that a correlatin matrix $C$ is always positive semi-definite ie for all $v \in \mathbb R^n$ we have $v^T C v \geq 0$.
Doesn't it implies  that for all eigenvalues $\lambda_i$of $C$ with $i = 1, \cdots, n$ we have tha $\lambda_i \geq$ 0?

Comment: Yes. A positive semi-definite matrix only has non-negative eigenvalues: if $Cv = sv$ then $0\le v^TCv = v^Tsv = sv^Tv = s\|v\|^2$ hence $s\ge 0$.

Comment: Thaks @amsmath ! Why I find many references in the literature about problems with the correlation matrix having negative values then? Like this reference from NAG documentation :https://www.nag.co.uk/IndustryArticles/fixing-a-broken-correlation-matrix.pdf. Is it purely because of numerical error. So eigenvalue are so sensitive to noise that even small noise can make the eigenvalues change significantly, some sort of non-linear effect ?

Comment: Read the first few pages of the article. Then you'll understand.